# How can I display a number stored in a variable rounded and with commas?

Tags: javascript, variables, format, rounding

My code in Javascript involves manipulating several variables and displaying a few of them in counters on-screen. Because of the math I'm using, I'll end up with numbers such as 1842.47167... or something similar. I want to display the number as 1,843 (rounded and with the "thousands" comma added). Does anyone have a simple and easy way to do it? See below for code I've tried.

```js
console.log(coins) //Output: 1842.4716796875
commaCoins = coins;
commaCoins = Math.round(coins);
commaCoins = coins.toLocaleString();
console.log(commaCoins) //Output: "1,842.472"
//Desired result: 1,843
```

Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to work with strings to achieve that.

Something like:

```js
const coins = 1842.4716796875;
const roundedCoins = Math.round(coins);
const dotFormat = roundedCoins / 1000
const commaFormat = dotFormat.toString().replace('.', ',');
console.log(commaFormat) // Output: 1,842
```

You can obviously do that in less step and use Math.ceil() if you need to round to the upper unit.

Comment: Thank you! The Math.ceil() function should do the trick for me. I also found that I can put parameters into the toLocaleString to include a minimum and maximum fraction place, but this method should work better for me.

Comment: Can you set this as answered ? :)